# Laravel - CSV - getting only one row as response

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5

I have one CSV file with two fields `field1` and `field2`. When I try to loop throught each row of my CSV file it only return first row of file.

Notice, that file is uploaded and valid.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Get File Contents
 */
 $csv = Reader::createFromPath(storage_path('folder/'.$FILE_NAME));
 $csv->setOffset(1);

/**
 * CSV Properties
 */
 $delimiter = $csv->getDelimiter();
 $enclosure = $csv->getEnclosure();

 /**
  * Processing CSV File
  */
 $temp_data = "";
 $csv->each(function($row) use ($position1, $position2, $delimiter, &$temp_data, $enclosure)
 {
    $temp_data .= $enclosure.$row[$position1].$enclosure.$delimiter.
                    $enclosure.$row[$position2].$enclosure."/n";

    echo $temp_data;
 });

 exit;
```

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting only the first row of the file?

Comment: Can you outline the process by which you declare your $csv variable as well as an example of you calling this function on a valid piece of data with arguments filled out? As it stands now, it doesn't seem to be an error with this specific piece of code.

Comment: $position1 = 0; $position2 = 1;

Comment: Okay, looking at the syntax, I'm assuming you're using the CSV plugin by The League (http://csv.thephpleague.com/). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CSV plugin by The League.

Comment: Alright, so there could be a few issues, as I'm not a master of this particular plugin.

Issue 1: When you do finally start spitting out multiple lines, you will start getting repeated echos.

Comment: "test1","a123"\n"test2","b123"\n

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your pass by reference for "temp_data".

So the other issue I could identify is that "the callable must return true to continue iterating over the CSV" from the Reader::each method in the documentation. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I have removed echo $temp_data and put return true. Outside of my each closure I put echo $temp_data and it's working fine.

Comment: That's great news, so should I put that down for the answer? Has it solved the issue completely?

Comment: yes, please. Put in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CSV plugin by The League (csv.thephpleague.com), the "each" method must return true on each iteration, or else it will stop running. This will cause the above method to only run 1 iteration before terminating, resulting in a single line output.